# Локализация laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locale

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста столкнулся с такой задачей. Есть интернет магазин написан на Laravel 5.4 Интернет магазин на русском языке, стоит задача добавить английский язык.

Как я вижу решение данной задачи:

1. Добавить в БД таблицу с локализацией.(en, ru)
2. Во всех существующих таблицах добавить внешний id на ru
3. Создать таблицы и наполнить их английским контентом и повесить на них внешний id на en
4. Проверять в зависимости от того какой префикс пришел и тянуть информацию с нужных таблиц.

Это очень трудоемкое решение, которое требует изменение структуры базы данных. Так же в Админку добавления полей под английский контент. А если например завтра скажут добавить еще и Немецкий язык, то все это нужно будет повторять еще раз и т.д.

Возможно есть какой то более простой способ данной реализации на Laravel 5.4?

Comment: В каждую таблицу с контентом добавляйте префиксы языков для текстовых полей, например, есть таблица `Pages`, у которой есть поля `Title`,`Description`, делайте из них `Title_ru`,`Title_en` и т.д. Затем, когда определяете текущий язык, делаете запросы вида **`SELECT Title_{$currentLang} AS Title`**

Comment: Доброе утро. Тут опять же нужно кардинально менять структуру БД, а именно в уже существующие таблицы с кучей данных добавлять поля. Хотелось бы сделать как то, чтоб не трогать существующую структуру БД.

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных, вместо выводящегося текста, храните ключ, по которому будете получать нужный текст в нужной локализации. И пользуйтесь встроенным в фреймворк решением: [localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization).